# Run cython code when extension module gets garbage collected

Tags: cython, cpython, python-internals

Is there a way to register a function within an Cython extenstion module such that this function is called when the Python garbage collector destroys the module object ?

Something like

`def __dealloc__(...)`

on module level ?

Comment: I have added cpython and python-internals, hoping that somebody could tell whether there is an "official" possibility to achieve that in pure Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is an explicit/official way to achieve that. However, you could add a global variable which will be destroyed, when the cython module is deallocated:

```
# foo.pyx:
class Observer:
    def __init__(self):
        print("module initialized")

    def __del__(self):
        print ("module deleted")

_o=Observer()
```

However, cythonizing it via `cythonize foo.pyx -i` will not lead to the desired effect:

```
[$] python -c `import foo`
module initialized
```

there is no "module deleted" printed to the console!

The problem: one cannot reload a cython-extension anyway (for example via `importlib.reload()`), so it gets only deallocated when the Python interpreter is shut down. But then there is no need to deallocate the resources ...

Cython keeps all global Python-variables in a global C-variable which is called `static PyObject *__pyx_d;` in the cythonized C-source; this is just a Python-dictionary. However, because there is a reference to the global `_o` in this not destroyed dictionary, the reference count of `_o` will never become 0 an thus the object doesn't get destroyed.

By setting `generate_cleanup_code=True` one can force Cython to generate a clean-up function which will be  put into the [`m_free`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#c.PyModuleDef.m_free)-slot of the [PyModuleDef](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#c.PyModuleDef) definition struct. For example with the following setup-file:

```
from distutils.core import setup

from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Compiler import Options

Options.generate_cleanup_code = True  #  this is important!

setup(
    name = "foo",
    ext_modules = cythonize("foo.pyx"),
)
```

And now after `python setup.py build_ext -i`:

```
[$] python -c "import foo"
module initialized
module deleted
```

it works as expected.

---

Because there is no `reload` for Cython-extensions, "module deleted" will be only seen when [`module_dealloc`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/621cebe81b1e6c8de10425955bf532d31ee4df42/Objects/moduleobject.c#L676) is called.

However, when the first listing were pure-Python, we would also see `module deleted` if `importlib.reload(foo)`  were called. In this case "module_dealloc" isn't used, but all references to global `_o` would be cleared and object would be destroyed.

Depending on what one  want, it might be either the expected or unexpected behavior.